# How to determine the number of bytes currently written by DataHandler.writeTo() method?

Tags: java, web-services, progress, mtom

I have to download file from web service using MTOM. Details of implementation below is not known to me. I do it this way, which works (response is an object returned from webservices and data is `javax.activation.DataHandler` type, `filePath` is file, where I want to save downloaded content):

```
DataHandler dataHandler = response.getData();
File file = new File(filePath);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
dataHandler.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
fileOutputStream.flush();
fileOutputStream.close();
```

But, what I need is figure out, how many bytes was written during download. It can take a long time, this way simply waits to finish downloading and then closes output stream and continues.

I know, I'll probably need another thread for reading number of written bytes and do something with it (need it for updating progressBar in SWT application).

My idea was to extend DataHandler someway, and then periodically ask, how many bytes is written). But I'm java noob and i don't know how to realize it.

Answer (score 1):

If you read everything to a `byte[]`, you'll need enough memory to hold the whole file. This may not be a problem for you now, but it's good to do not create this bad habit (which can easily put a server down).

[Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html) and [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CountingOutputStream.html) have a `CountingOutputStream` class that does exactly what you want, just count how many bytes where wrote. If you can't use this libraries, you can write a similar class, just implement `OutputStream`, receive another `OutputStream` in the constructor and each method just increment the `byteCount` and delegates.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research, and I overlooked DataHandler method called getInputStream() before. Using this method I can do what I need:

```
DataHandler dataHandler = response.getData();
File file = new File(filePath);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

// got Input Stream from DataHandler
InputStream is = dataHandler.getInputStream();

// then I can manage writing file my way        
byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int br;
Long bytesWritten = 0L;
while ((br = is.read(data)) > 0) {
    fileOutputStream.write(data, 0, br);
    bytesWritten = bytesWritten + br;
    // call some method to update UI progressBar
}

// this is now useless:
// dataHandler.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
fileOutputStream.flush();
fileOutputStream.close();
```